# Why might SELinux issue a Permission Denied error when accessing an upstream Node.js server's default routes, but not static files like image files?

Tags: nginx, node.js, selinux

**Environment:** Nginx reverse proxy serving static resources and using `proxy_pass` to serve resources from 2 separate Node.js upstream server instances.

**Simplified example nginx.conf:**

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location ~* \.(jpg)$ {}
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}

server {
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    location ~* \.(jpg)$ {}
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

The top block can serve both static files and Node.js resources through `proxy_pass` without error.  The bottom block can serve static files but throws an SELinux permissions error when I hit the Node.js server through `proxy_pass`.  With SELinux set to permissive no error is thrown.

**Client error:**
Chrome displays a 502 Bad Gateway error.

**From the error log:**

```
2020/12/11 14:49:03 [crit] 2113#2113: *24 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8081 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, server: subdomain.example.com, request: "GET /random-page HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/random-page", host: "subdomain.example.com", referrer: "https://subdomain.example.com/"
```

I have `httpd_can_network_relay` set to on.  This seems to be enough to make the top block work but not the bottom block.

`httpd_can_network_relay        (on   ,   on)  Allow httpd to can network relay`

What else might I need to set in SELinux to get rid of the error?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested below I threw the error and then ran,

```
$ sudo ausearch -m AVC -ts recent
```

The error in the log is outside my ability to understand it.  I'm not sure where to start.

> time->Fri Dec 11 20:39:08 2020 type=PROCTITLE
> msg=audit(1607744348.594:791):
> proctitle=6E67696E783A20776F726B65722070726F63657373 type=SYSCALL
> msg=audit(1607744348.594:791): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no
> exit=-13 a0=11 a1=55c9f3d0ab50 a2=10 a3=7ffeab2adb5c items=0 ppid=1187
> pid=1191 auid=4294967295 uid=989 gid=986 euid=989 suid=989 fsuid=989
> egid=986 sgid=986 fsgid=986 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="nginx"
> exe="/usr/sbin/nginx" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
> type=AVC msg=audit(1607744348.594:791): avc:  denied  { name_connect }
> for  pid=1191 comm="nginx" dest=8081
> scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
> tcontext=system_u:object_r:transproxy_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
> permissive=0

Comment: Generate the error, and then run this command to get the specific SELinux denied message: `ausearch -m AVC -ts recent` - when you do that, you should get a better idea of why, exactly, SELinux is denying something.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks David I updated my answer to reflect your advice.  Unfortunately the error is not readable.  At least not by me.

Comment: `httpd_can_network_relay` does not actually open all outbound ports; there's no reason to use it here. See the linked post for the solution to this issue.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because these are ports on upstream node.js servers being referenced with `proxy_pass` is that the same as external `http_port_t` ports?

Comment: @btw my apologies I should have used the real port numbers instead of 1111 and 2222.  I never thought that was relevant.  I'll fix my question they were 8080 and 8081.

Comment: `httpd_can_network_relay` opens port 8080 (and a few others) but not port 8081.